# Extreme Value Theorem on Manifold

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact manifold. Then any $h \in C^{\infty}(M)$, $h$ has a maximum and minimum value.

Since $M$ is compact we know that $M$ can be covered with finitely many charts, but I'm not sure where to go after that.

Comment: You do not need the fact that $M$ is a smooth manifold, you just need the fact that $M$ is a compact topological space. And you do not need the fact that $h$ is $C^\infty$, you just need the fact that $h:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. So this is basic point-set topology.

Answer (score 10):

$h$ is continuous, so its image is compact since $M$ is compact, every compact subset of $R$ has a minimum and a maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The following fact may be helpful: Smooth maps are continuous, and a continuous map from a compact space preserves compactness. This you can prove by pulling back an open cover of the image to the preimage, chopping it down, and then making sure it maps to a finite open cover.

From here, you know what every compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ looks like: namely, closed and bounded. Will the image include a maximum/minimum value?

Comment: Don't all continuous maps preserve compactness, without any Hausdorff requirement?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I was proving a stronger statement in my head. I'll edit my answer.